# Cannot Statically link MySQL C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, linker, g++

I am trying to compile a rather simple piece of code using the MySQL C++ Connector Library. I am linking the library statically to my application.

```
g++ "./source/main.cpp" -std=c++11 -m64 -static -pthread -lmysqlcppconn -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lfastcgipp -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -o "/var/www/index.fcgi"
```

However, when I execute this command to compile the program, I am left with hundreds of `undefined reference to ...` errors. Few examples:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn.a(mysql_client_api.cpp.o): In function `sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy::affected_rows(st_mysql*)':
(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `mysql_affected_rows'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn.a(mysql_client_api.cpp.o): In function `sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy::autocommit(st_mysql*, char)':
(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `mysql_autocommit'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libmysqlcppconn.a(mysql_client_api.cpp.o): In function `sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy::close(st_mysql*)':
(.text+0x1ac): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I link the library is linked dynamically, everything works fine.

How do I link this library statically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are statically linking, you have to reference all the libraries you use, even indirectly, whereas this is not necessary when dynamically linking.

Theses undefined functions are located in the C MySQL API, so you should add -lmysqlclient